# Как сделать привязку двух объектов через скрипт в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня **есть два рядом находящихся объекта**, которые мне нужно **связать между собой через скрипт**. При этом, нужно сделать так, чтобы **при перемещении одного объекта**, вместе с ним **перемещался и другой**. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли так сделать, и если можно, то как?

P.S В Unity совсем новичок, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось в разы проще, чем я думал:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Parent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    public void SetParent(GameObject newParent)
    {
        player.transform.parent = newParent.transform;
    }
}
```