# Разбиение блока на составляющие

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать из двух блоков один, я нашёл вот здесь - [Как сделать привязку двух объектов через скрипт в Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1369673/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%b2-unity)

А вот как сделать, чтобы при должном ударе о стены блок распадался на составляющие его блоки?

Comment: transform.parent = null

Answer (score 0):

Для этого применяются несколько техник.

Если вы работаете с физикой Rigidbody в Юнити, вы можете создать два наследника(child) в родительском объекте, предварительно разрезанных в каком-либо 3Д редакторе. После того, как вы задетектируете попадание, скройте или удалите Parent объект, не забудьте предварительно извлечь наследников, сбросив им родительский объект.

Далее вы можете задать импульс дочерним объектам по направлению вашего попадания или любым другим приемлемым способом.
Подробнее об импульсе написано в официальной документации с различными вариантами использования: [ForceMode.Impulse](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html)